# Cython overloading "no suitable method found"

Tags: python, python-2.7, constructor, overriding, cython

I am having trouble accessing overloaded constructors in a C++ class through Cython.  I am trying to wrap a C++ class as described [here](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/wrapping_CPlusPlus.html#create-cython-wrapper-class).  The class has multiple constructors with the same number of arguments, differing only by type, such as the class mentioned [here](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/wrapping_CPlusPlus.html#overloading).  However, Cython has trouble deciding which constructor to call, giving the error "no suitable method found".

For instance, given foo.h as follows

```
class Foo 
{
    public:
        int which_constructor;

        Foo(int){ which_constructor = 1; }
        Foo(bool){ which_constructor = 2; };

        ~Foo();
};
```

and pyfoo.pyx as follows

```
from libcpp cimport bool as bool_t

cdef extern from "foo.h":
    cdef cppclass Foo:
        Foo(int)
        Foo(bool_t)
        int which_constructor

cdef class PyFoo:
    cdef Foo *thisptr      # hold a C++ instance which we're wrapping

    def __cinit__( self, *args, **kwargs):
        # get list of arg types to distinquish overloading
        args_types = []
        for arg in args:
            args_types.append(type(arg))

        if (args_types == [int]):
            self.thisptr = new Foo(args[0])
        elif (args_types == [bool]):
            self.thisptr = new Foo(args[0])
        else:
            pass

    def which_constructor(self):
        return self.thisptr.which_constructor
```

and a setup file setup_pyfoo.py as follows

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(
    ext_modules = cythonize(
        Extension("pyfoo", ["pyfoo.pyx"],
            language="c++",
        )
    )
)
```

when I attempt to compile, I get the following error

```
C:\Users\bennett.OCM\Documents\Python\Cython>python setup_pyfoo.py build_ext --i
nplace
Compiling pyfoo.pyx because it changed.
Cythonizing pyfoo.pyx

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
        for arg in args:
            args_types.append(type(arg))

        # four differnent constructors.
        if (args_types == [int]):
            self.thisptr = new Foo(args[0])
                                 ^
------------------------------------------------------------

pyfoo.pyx:20:34: no suitable method found

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...

        # four differnent constructors.
        if (args_types == [int]):
            self.thisptr = new Foo(args[0])
        elif (args_types == [bool]):
            self.thisptr = new Foo(args[0])
                                 ^
------------------------------------------------------------

pyfoo.pyx:22:34: no suitable method found
```

If I remove one or other of the constructor definitions in pyfoo.pyx, things work correctly, even though the multiple constructors still exist in foo.h.  I suspect that Cython needs to be coerced into calling a particular constructor.  I just don't know how to help it.  Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can cast your arguments explicitly:

```
if (args_types == [int]):
    self.thisptr = new Foo(<int> args[0])
elif (args_types == [bool]):
    self.thisptr = new Foo(<bool_t> args[0])
else:
    pass
```

Be sure to cast to `<bool_t>` and not `<bool>`, otherwise it will give you an ambiguous overloading error.